# Best way to modify PDFs using iText?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext

Scenario: Clients will be providing me with PDF-templates. I need to programmatically fill these with information. 
**Question:** What is the best way to do this?

Say for example a client sends me the beautiful template seen below and I want to fill in the Price Field. The research I've done so far has led me to believe that there is no way for me to programmatically 'understand' where the Price Field is, is this correct? A workaround I've heard of is creating another template on top of the existing template. I want to make this as hassle-free as possible, is there a program that let's me create a template easily using say drag-and drop forms, with another template as a base? Then perhaps I could load the clients template, then my own created template, populate that with values and merge it all into one PDF. Is this a sensible approach?

Very thankful for any thoughts or suggestions. 
 [image]

Comment: It seems as if the clients will be required to use Form Fields in their templates. If so, this link (http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10086882/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-cnet.aspx) seems to provide a very easy solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10086882/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-cnet.aspx) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to use birt viewer plugin for eclipse  reporting tool.. you can generate reports on templates .. and there is automatically pdf creator..

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage.php

Comment: Sounds great. Do you know if there's a visual studio equivalent?